# Counting phonetically similar words in a column in SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table of phrases inserted into it. I want a count of similar sounding (phonetically) phrases (entire text) and show a count. I was able to do that using Soundex using the following. It works if they are all single words perfectly but if I introduce phrases it is only matching the first word in the phrase.

Example:

- Beatles, Baetles, Beetles - count 3
- The Beatles, The Rolling Stones - count 2 (when I am expecting it to be 1 each).

Here is my T-SQL

```
select top 3  
    count(*) as count, 
    dbo.getWord(soundex(word)) as word, 
    soundex(word) 
from 
    words 
group by 
    soundex(word) 
order by 
    count desc;
```

getWord function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getWord] 
    (@code nvarchar(4))
RETURNS nvarchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return_value nvarchar(50);

    SELECT TOP 1 @return_value = word 
    FROM words 
    WHERE soundex(word) = @code
    
    RETURN @return_value
END;
```

[image: Results]

So this solution does not work, I tried to implement another function that checks the Damerau-Levenshtein algorithm in T-SQL which takes 2 words and max distance but how can I use that for my needs.

Any suggestion or solution to a similar problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Though not explicitly documented, `SOUNDEX` is intended to be used against *words* not phrases. For your values like `'Beatles'` and `'Beetles'` it therefore works as you expect, however, for `'The Rolling Stones'` and `'The Beatles'` it doesn't. Instead `SOUNDEX` is returning the "sound" for the *first*  word in the string, which for both is `'The'`, and so the `SOUNDEX` for both is `'T000'`

What you could do is remove the spaces from the strings, to treat it as one word:

```sql
SELECT SOUNDEX(REPLACE(V.String,' ','')) AS Sound,
       V.String,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SOUNDEX(REPLACE(V.String,' ',''))) AS [Count]
FROM (VALUES('The Rolling Stones'),
            ('The Beatles'),
            ('Beetles'),
            ('Baetles'),
            ('Beatles')) V(String);
```

This returns the following dataset:

```
Sound String             Count
----- ------------------ -----------
B342  Baetles            3
B342  Beetles            3
B342  Beatles            3
T134  The Beatles        1
T645  The Rolling Stones 1
```

An alternative approach would be to get the sound of each word and then aggregate the returned sounds, and group on those. In any on premises versions of SQL Server you will need to use something other than `STRING_SPLIT` and use a user defined function or method that returns the ordinal position. If you are on an Azure SQL Database (and hopefully SQL Server 2022+) then `STRING_SPLIT` has an `Ordinal` parameter you can use.

I use `STRING_SPLIT` with the `Ordinal` parameter here to demonstrate the idea but (again) if you are using on-premises SQL Server you'll need to use a different method (such as `DelimitedSplit8K`/`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD` or a JSON splitter).

```sql
SELECT SE.Sound,
       V.String,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SE.Sound) AS [Count]
FROM (VALUES('The Rolling Stones'),
            ('The Beatles'),
            ('Beetles'),
            ('Baetles'),
            ('Beatles')) V(String)
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT STRING_AGG(SOUNDEX(SS.[value]),'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SS.Ordinal)
                  FROM STRING_SPLIT(V.String,' ',1) SS) SE(Sound);
```

This returns the following dataset:

```
Sound        String             Count
------------ ------------------ -----------
B342         Beetles            3
B342         Baetles            3
B342         Beatles            3
T000B342     The Beatles        1
T000R452S352 The Rolling Stones 1
```

Comment: Awesome, before reading your reply I tried the same by replacing space with "-" and it didn't work and then I removed the - and it worked. Thank you this worked like a charm.

Comment: You're welcome, @PrakashNakka . If it answer the question, then please do mark the answer as the solution, so that future readers know it was helpful.